# Regarding one electron energy levels

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, applied-physics

I was reading a book on quantum transport by Supriyo Datta.Where he mentions "For the ionization levels, the one-electron energies εn represent the difference
between the ground state energy EG(N) of the neutral N-electron atom and the
nth energy level En(N − 1) of the positively ionized (N − 1)-electron atom:
εn = EG(N) − En(N − 1) "

Can anyone please explain that means?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is rather awkwardly put, in your book. Let me try and shed some light on the matter with a schematic.

[image: Ionisation schematic]

Left is a neutral magnesium atom with all electrons present (shells filled as $2,8,2$, $Z=12$). The electrons are represented by the Principal quantum numbers of the shells they belong to. A removed electron is represented by "+". $E_0$, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are the total energy levels.

First note that the energy levels of the shells are in fact negative ($<0$) because the potential energy of a free, stationary electron is zero. The ground state energy of a hydrogen atom e.g. is $-13.6\:\mathrm{eV}$.

Moving from left to middle we carry out the *first ionisation* by removing an $n=3$ electron. This leaves an $Mg^+$ ion. Note that due to the loss of charge, the ion *shrinks somewhat* with respect to the neutral atom and the $E_1$ level is lower than $E_0$.

The first ionisation energy is:

$$\Delta E_{1st}=0+E_1-E_0>0$$

Moving from middle to right we carry out the *second ionisation* by removing the second $n=3$ electron. This leaves an $Mg^{2+}$ ion. Note again that due to the loss of charge, the $Mg^{2+}$ ion *shrinks somewhat* with respect to the $Mg^+$ and the $E_1$ level moves to $E_2$.

The second ionisation energy is:

$$\Delta E_{2nd}=0+E_2-E_1>0$$

Note that $\Delta E_{2nd}$ is larger than $\Delta E_{1st}$.

An important corollary is that the third ionisation energy will be much larger because the energy level of the $n=2$ electrons is so much lower.

Comment: Then what does Eg(N)-En(N-1) represent?

Comment: I don't know to be honest: I've never come across it before.